# sql server 2005 installation error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

hi 
While installing sql server 2005 i got an error as

None of the selected features can be installed or upgraded. Setup cannot proceed since no effective change is being made to the machine. To continue, click Back and then select features to install. To exit SQL Server Setup, click Cancel.

I have uninstalled sql server 2005,sql native client ,sql support files.

but i got the same error.Am struggling lot with this error.help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try:

1. check if you installed SQL Server Express first, then  Uninstall SQL Server and Express, then re-install SQL Server.
2. run the setup.exe from the SQL installation source from your Run command with the parameter SKUUPGRADE=1 or UPGRADE=1.